# Embed Google Maps inside Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I have a responsive design where multiple maps are inserted in each of the bootstrap carousel slides.

Using the latest Google maps API some of the maps look zoomed out to the antartic and horrible

[image: Issue]

After some research i discovered a similar issue with tabs, since the hidden content. But i could not manage to get any of the proposed responses to work on my project.

last code i tried was

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    })
});
```

But i'm getting the error **"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"**

The maps are stored on my DB and embed using the code that the API outputs

Example :

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1961.5104998775728!2d-66.88076565031373!3d10.499010518599084!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0xfdd50a9e95ba1b19!2sEnoba+Sistemas!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2sve!4v1415992894629!zoom=18" width="1350" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I'm stuck right now

Comment: It would probably need to be in the `slid.bs.carousel` event: *This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.* I am confused though as whether you are using Maps Embed API or the Google Maps JavaScript API (as tagged in your question).

Comment: tried with `slid.bs.carousel` and the same thing happens, i'm using Maps Embed API or well the project was made like that in the CMS part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this with the Google Map iframe to use jquery.livequery (https://github.com/hazzik/livequery) to check if it's visible and then re-load the source if it's not.

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/guzada/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // REQUIRES jquery.livequery
   $('.google-map iframe:visible').livequery(function() {
     var mapFrame = $(this);
     if (!$(mapFrame).hasClass('map-refreshed')) {
       mapFrame.attr('src', mapFrame.attr('src')+'');
       mapFrame.addClass('map-refreshed');
    }
});
  
});
```

HTML

```
  <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
           <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 google-map">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Eiffel%20Tower%2C%20Avenue%20Anatole%20France%2C%20Paris%2C%20France&key=AIzaSyAFUKSu28KvFk67YcSlUWeUJ2TpcifSVmQ"></iframe>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 google-map">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Trafalgar%20Square%2C%20London%2C%20United%20Kingdom&key=AIzaSyAFUKSu28KvFk67YcSlUWeUJ2TpcifSVmQ"></iframe>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
     </div>
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
     </ol>
  </div>
  <!--/.carousel-->
```

Comment: Hello Christina Thanks for your answer, one more thing while trying, what do i need to include for that library? i just zip-downloaded it but it has a lot of files

Comment: the dist folder has the  jquery.livequery.min.js file that you put in your assets/js folder or equiv and link to it just like any other js, AFTER the jquery library and usually in the footer of the document, then following that file and the jQuery library AND bootstrap.min.js, you add your js file, making a file in your code editor, and linking to it just like the other scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christina your solution worked just fine.

Comment: works for all the stuff, tabs, collapse, and modal if the classes are the same {google-map on the embed-responsive}.